# javascript download ended trigger

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a webpage which displays a gallery of photos. After the user selects the photos he/she wants to download, the user then clicks the **Download** button to download the photos. The javascript code iterates through the selected photos and simulates a "click" event for each one. Unfortunately, javascript allows only one "click" event to fired and handled at any one time. The result is that only the last photo is downloaded because each subsequent simulated "click" event destroys the previous one. I need a way of pausing the execution of the script, and checking when the file has completed downloading before continuing with the next iteration of the loop. I've used the **alert()** function in the code below to simulate this behaviour.

```
    function Download() {
        var thm;
        for( thm of thumbnails ) {
            var download_evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
                view: window,
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true,
            });
            var cancelled;
            try {
                if (thm.selected == 1 ) {
                    document.getElementById(thm.photo_id).type = "application/octet-stream";
                    cancelled = !document.getElementById(thm.photo_id).dispatchEvent(download_evt);
                    alert("wait");
                }
            } catch(err) {
                alert(err.message);
            }
        }
    }
```

The javascript code below handles the user click on the thumbnail. It highlights the thumbnail and flags the photo for download and prevents the default action of the anchor tag.

```
    function SelectPhoto(btn_el){
        // if the user clicked the anchor,
        // select the photo but don\'t download it.
        if ( event.isTrusted == false ) {
            return true;
        }
        btn_el.classList.toggle("w3-theme-d1");
        var idx = thumbnails.findIndex(FindPhotoId,btn_el.id);
        thumbnails[idx].selected = 1 - thumbnails[idx].selected;
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    function FindPhotoId(thm) {
        return (thm.photo_id * 1) == (this * 1);
    }
```

The anchor tag looks like this:

```html
<a href="/image.jpg' 
   type="application/octet-stream"
   download
   class="w3-border w3-btn photosheet" 
   id="123"
   onclick="SelectPhoto(this);">
   <img src="image.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%;">
</a>
```

Comment: This is a very bad way to solve this problem. Instead try to keep track of which pictures are selected, and then when the download button is clicked, download the selected pictures.

Comment: That's exactly what the code is trying to do.

Comment: You are trying to initiate click events. I meant that you shouldn't do this, instead  initiate whatever JS code runs to handle click event. If you can share the code that runs on the click event, I can provide a complete answer

Comment: It's an <a> tag with an href. When the user clicks on the thumbnail, it highlights the border around it. I've disabled the default action using event.preventDefault(). The photos can only be downloaded when the user clicks the Download button.

Comment: Here's the JS code that handles the click on the anchor tag. function SelectPhoto(btn_el){
            // if the user clicked the anchor,
            // select the photo but don\'t download it.
            if ( event.isTrusted == false ) {
                return true;
            }
            btn_el.classList.toggle("w3-theme-d1");
            var idx = thumbnails.findIndex(FindPhotoId,btn_el.id);
            thumbnails[idx].selected = 1 - thumbnails[idx].selected;
            event.preventDefault();
        }

Comment: You could serve the downloaded images using Php. When the user clicks on the download button, you can send the list of selected photos to a server side Php script. The script can create a single zip file containing all the photos. Once the zip file has been created, the name of the file can be returned by the script. The user can then be redirected to the url pointing to the zip file

Comment: Thanks, Nadir, but a single zip file is not an option in this case. I really need a solution to the problem as stated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that does exactly what I want, so don't bother investigating this, thanks. The solution is to change the Download() function to run asynchronously, and then use a Promise to await the response from the dispatch of the click event.